# Blender 3.4.1 Weight Paint Not Working

Tags: weight-paint-mode

[image]

Object is supposed to turn blue, and all I get is this 'wireframe' look and cannot do absolutely anything. In viewport overlays, Weight Paint Opacity is set to 1, and it is selectable in the viewport. If I add another object weight paint works, but not for this cat model.

Comment: You are in "face masking" mode (button to the right of mode select) and it appears that you don't have any faces selected.  Disable face masking or select some faces.

Comment: @Nathan That was the issue! Thnx!